# How can I avoid explicitly declaring directory paths in C or C++ #include directives?

Tags: c++, c, header

I am making a simulator and have written lots of files and headers. The problem is whenever I include a file I give the relative path of the particular file. For example a typical code in my application would begin like

```
#ifndef AI_H
#define AI_H

#include <cstdlib>

#include "../world/world.h"
#include "pathPlan.h"
#include "skills/tryskill.h"
#include "../info/condition.h"
#include "dataStructures/destination.h"
#include "../params/gamePlay.h"
#include "../modules/controlModule.h"


class ai
{
    public:

etc etc
```

I want to avoid using the relative paths. For example I want to directly include "tryskill.h" and "destination.h" without giving the absolute paths. That way I wont need to bother if I change the location of any particular file. I am using Ubuntu 9.10. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since you're on Ubuntu, can we assume you're using GCC as well? Are you using a makefile/build system? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: It's generally a *good* idea to use relative paths... what if you have the same file name in two different directories? For instance, `info/constants.h` and `params/constants.h`? You may want to set a base include path to say, a `/includes/` folder, but anything below that should be specified as part of the include.

Comment: I am using QT for generating the MAKEFILE. Is there a way in which I could edit the PRO file or MAKEFILE so as to include the directory to search for header files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really it all depends on your include path, different compilers might call it different things but in gcc

```
-Idir  Append directory dir to the list of directories searched for include files.
```

So in your example you would specify `../world etc...` in the list of directories in `-I`

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if you're compiling from the command line, you would supply include search paths to your compiler (gcc example: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html). If you're using an IDE, you should be able to specify include search paths to your IDE and your IDE will pass these on to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using paths that are relative to your program's/library's top-level include path. There are many different ways to do this, depending on how you are building your program. If you are using the [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) build system -- which I strongly urge you to use -- then you would use the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` command:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)
```

If your "info/condition.h" file is located in "include/blah/info/condition.h", then you would include it with:

```
#include <blah/info/condition.h>
```

If you are compiling from the commandline with g++, you can use the `-I` commandline switch:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ... fileN.cpp -I./include
```

If you are using Make, you can ensure that this is flag is used by adding the following line:

```
CPPFLAGS += -I./include
```

Another possibility, though one I do not recommend, is to define the environment variable `CPATH`:

```
# Note the following is what you would do in BASH:
export CPATH="$CPATH":"`pwd`/include"
```

Comment: I am using the QMAKE command to generate the MAKEFILE can I manually add CPPFLAGS += -I./include inside the MAKEFILE generated by QMAKE ??

Comment: For QMAKE, you use the variable INCLUDEPATH: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

Comment: Where do I include the INCLUDEPATH directive ? I tried writing it in the .PRO file. It doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Food for thoughts: what is the alternative ?

```
#include "pathPlan.h"
#include "exception.h"
#include "world.h"
#include "exception.h" // uh ?
```

I've always been wary of having too many paths declared in the include paths variable, the issue is that the more paths there are the more likely you are to get a filename clash, and it's annoying to debug, really.

I much prefer using this:

```
// 3rd party libraries
#include <3rdParty1/foo.h>
#include <3rdParty2/foo.h>

// Projects I depend on
#include "myProject1/bar.h"

// Current project, from the include directory
#include "currentProject/foobar.h"
#include "currentProject/another.h"

// Current project, from the source directory (private includes)
#include "../world.h"
#include "../detail/helper.h"
```

Which means for a given project "thingy" I have the following file:

```
// in thingy/1-3-0-2/include/thingy/foo.h

namespace thingy  // base namespace is project name
                  // namespace hierarchy identical to folders hierarchy
{
}
```

And then I have the following on my compilation line:

```
-I${Repository}/thingy/1-3-0-2/include
```

Sure it's a bit more typing, but it helps keeping things all tidy:

- namespace / folder correlation makes it easier to find the location of the file
- projects prefixing makes it impossible for 2 files from different projects to be mixed up even when they have the same name

Answer (score 1):

Compilers will let you specify on the command line (or a response/configuration file) the directories to search for header files.  You can generally configure this in a makefile or IDE's project settings if you're driving a build using one of those tools.

However, in general, I prefer to specify the relative path for headers that 'belong' to a project (as opposed to maybe libraries that are used across projects).  That way when you add a new module, you don't have to muck around with project settings or make files to get things to continue to build.

That's if you like to keep the header for a module along-side the module's implementation instead of having the headers piled into a single (or small set of) directories. Either organization is arguably as good as the other.

Comment: I am using QT for generating the MAKEFILE. Is there a way in which I could edit the PRO file or MAKEFILE so as to include the directory to search for header files.

Comment: Assuming you're using `qmake` to manage the `makefile`, you'll want to have an `INCLUDEPATH` variable that lists the directories to search: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath

Comment: Where do I include the INCLUDEPATH directive ? I tried writing it in the .PRO file. It doesnt seem to be working

Comment: At or near the top of the .pro file, e.g. INCLUDEPATH += ../world ./skills

Answer (score 0):

Any good IDE or makefile will allow you to list relative search paths for files.  Look into this for your solution.