# Regarding the #include preprocessor directive for vector cast environment

Tags: unit-testing, vector, c-preprocessor

As per my code in filename.c,

```
#include "FOUNDATION/FOUNDATION.h"
```

Actually I have to run the vector cast (unit testing tool) for the filename.c.
so since the "FOUNDATION.h" is not present in the corresponding path mentioned,
vector cast compilation provides the error like no such file/directory.
can we replace

```
#include "FOUNDATION/FOUNDATION.h"
```

with my specified path where actually the "FOUNDATION.h" is present.

Comment: can anyone please reply.

Comment: Usually the idea is to not use paths in includes and instead setup the include search paths appropriatly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I avoid explicitly declaring directory paths in C or C++ #include directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741422/how-can-i-avoid-explicitly-declaring-directory-paths-in-c-or-c-include-direct)